# How to make validation for boolean field?

Tags: laravel

In laravel I defined bool field

```
$table->boolean('published')->default(false);
```

and I defined validation

```
[published] => nullable|in:0,1
```

But submitting data

```
    'published'        => false,
```

I got validation error(false is passed as epmty value), but value false is valid here.
I think I would use

```
        'published'        => 0,
```

But that seems not good for me as I want to show that I pass FALSE parameter.
How can I change validation rule in this case ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.2",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `boolean` instead of `in:0,1` [rule-boolean](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-boolean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validate $request with below rules:

```
$request->validate([            
    'published' => ['boolean', 'nullable']            
        ]);
```

Comment: why `$table` in your code ? he is showing migration file.